# What does it mean if my urine test is positive for ketones, hemoglobin, and leukocytes?

Tags: test-results, urine, hemoglobin, ketone

**What would be some of the reasons/explanations as to why one's urine test would test positive for ketones, hemoglobin, and leukocytes?**

I'm not even sure what ketones and leukocytes are.

Thanks.

Comment: Ketone bodies are basically oxidized carbons (carbonyls); they can indicate certain things about metabolism in your body because they may come from fatty acid breakdown. I'm sure someone can give a more detailed answer about ketones. Leukocytes are white blood cells. Positive for hemoglobin and leukocytes may indicate blood in the urine. Did you ask your provider to interpret/explain the results to you?